# Get value of an array using dynamic index in handlebar template

Tags: handlebars.js, marionette

I am new to Handlebars.

I have created an ItemView which is used in CompositeView. Values for this template rendering correctly.

```
var singleMonth = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    template: {
      type: 'handlebars',
      template: monthTemplate
    },
    months: [ 'JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','JUN','JUL','AUG','SEP','OCT','NOV','DEC' ],
    templateHelpers: function() {
      var helpers = {};
      helpers.months = this.months;
      return helpers;
    }
  });
```

and this is my template

```
<td>{{ months.@index.[7] }}</td><td>{{ [12] }}</td>
```

I want to get respective month value based on value of [7] which will be index for months array.

`for Ex. if [7] is 3 then I want to get expression value as 'MAR'`.

I am not able to get how to do this.

Can you please tell me how can I do this ?

(NOTE: I don't want to use #each or any loop here )

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Despite the possible syntax error in your template, the template itself should not be so smart.

Keep it stupid like

```
<td>{{ thisMonth }}</td>
```

Then build `thisMonth` in `templateHelpers`

```
templateHelpers: function() {
  // The reason for _this is: `this` means model in templateHelpers.
  _this = this; 
  return {
    thisMonth: _this.months[7]
  }
};
```

Comment: I did this way only...!! Thanks